# Mesh Face Count Different in Edit and Object Mode

Tags: mesh, faces

I'm new to Blender so go easy! I've modelled a bottle in Blender and I have a label on it. The label is really blocky so I increased the number of faces with the subdivide tool. Problem is this only shows in edit mode, in all other views, including render, the label is still blocky and I can't seem to smooth it out. No modifiers on it and if I do try and smooth it with a modifier it completely destroys the shape of the object which is just a plain cylinder. Top picture is edit mode with correct number of faces, bottom is object and that also follows for all other views.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please share your file, it's a bit hard to understand, use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks, here it is. I've also been messing with another cylinder in this project to see if I can get a smoother one but then the wrapping of the label goes awry, seems to want to wrap it across 4 segments of the cylinder rather than just one complete wrap.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5765" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5765/)

Comment: So essentially I want the label to be smooth, not as it is in every view except the edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess your purpose was to create an object that looked smooth. To do it, first you need to press the *Smooth Shading* option in the *Tools* panel of your *3D View*. Then you need to have a high-poly mesh. The easiest way to have a high-poly mesh is not to create a lot of edges, because it will be heavy and very tedious to work with, it's much better to fake it with a *Subsurf* modifier.

What I see is that you have both a high-poly and a *Subsurf* modifier, so as you don't have any reason to have a high-poly you have to go back to a low-poly, and keep your *Subsurf* to fake the high-polyness.

Also, about your *Subsurf* modifier, decrease the *Subdivisions* values to 2 and 2, and choose the *Catmull-Clark* option rather than *Simple*.

Now, despite having both a high-poly and a *Subsurf*, you still have a cylinder that looks squared. It's because the vertical edge loops are aligned on the same axis, 5 by 5, so they create faces. So even if the *Smooth Shading* + the *Subsurf* should make your cylinder look round, these aligned edge loops tend to flatten the faces.

So to fix this, either restart from scratch with a low poly cylinder (like for example 12 vertices), or delete the edge loops that create all these faces around your current cylinder.

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent explanation, I shall give that all a try! Many thanks for taking the time to look at it.